# data binding combobox in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

Code-Behind :

```
public class TestVariableClass
{
    List<string> States;

    public TestVariableClass()
    {
    States = new List<string> { "MP", "CG"};           
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="TestApplication.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestApplication"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <local:TestVariableClass x:Key="StatesInIt"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top" DataContext="{StaticResource StatesInIt}">
        <Label>States</Label>
        <ComboBox Width="140" Margin="5" x:Name="comboBoxStates" ItemsSource="{Binding States}"></ComboBox>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

I simply dont see my comboBox field getting populated when I run the application. Is my way of data binding correct ? 
I was trying to connect this comboBox with my database column. But after trying out few things I realised the error was in the binding itself.

Comment: I think States needs to be a public property, i.e.: `public List<string> States { get; set; }` Also, are there any data binding errors showing up in the Output window?

Comment: I did change it to public and tried. It didnt work.
And there are no errors in the error list. I am able to compile and run the application. But the field is not populated with data i provided.

Comment: The program will compile and run fine, but if there are data binding errors during the execution of the program, they will show up separately, in the Output window in Visual Studio. There's nothing there?

Comment: Error shows like this :

System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'States' property not found on 'object' ''TestVariableClass' (HashCode=42753953)'. BindingExpression:Path=States; DataItem='TestVariableClass' (HashCode=42753953); target element is 'ComboBox' (Name='comboBoxStates'); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable')

Comment: So that's telling you the data binding can't find your property States in your model class. Try defining a private class variable `private List<string> _states;` and then a public accessor for it `public List<string> States { get { return _states; } }`

Comment: Thanks for the help. That worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are binding to in your model class needs to be a public property of the class:

```
private List<string> _states;

public List<string> States { get { return _states; } }
```

As a note, you won't be able to modify the collection of States and have it update automatically in the view. For that, you could use an ObservableCollection instead of a List. You may not need that functionality though.