# Creating a class to hold a collection for data binding?

Tags: c#, wpf

This has troubled me for the last two weeks, I am trying to make a list that I can call to use in a WPF control. I just can't seem to get the code right.

I have [Pro C# 5.0 and the .NET 4.5 Framework (Expert's Voice in .NET)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430242337) and Chapter 9 has a very detailed description of what they are and how to use them. But to my short comings I cannot for the life of me do what I am trying to do.

What I am trying to do.

- Create a class to hold a list of `string` data
- Use that list to populate a WPF control (In this example a combo box) via Data binding.
- extract the string selected from the list.

I made a separate class, It will only ever be a one dimensional list BTW.

```
class CollectionClass
    {
        public static void ListOfStuff()
        {
            List<string> Stuff = new List<string>();
            Stuff.Add("Stuff1");
            Stuff.Add("Stuff2");
            Stuff.Add("Stuff3");
            Stuff.Add("Stuff4");
        }
    }
```

And my XAML for a combo box,

```
<ComboBox Name="NamesComboBox" Background="Yellow" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Margin="5" 
                          DisplayMemberPath = "Value" SelectedValuePath="Key" 
                          ItemsSource="{Binding UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Path=Stuff}" 
                          SelectedItem="{Binding UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Path=SelectedStuff}"
```

And to call the method,

```
CollectionClass.ListOfStuff();
```

Obviously this does not work, so I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction. Do I need to call the `method` in the `Main.xaml.cs`?

Comment: There is no easy answer because your example is way off. There is no single fix, you don't have a proper binding, you don't have a viewmodel, your method does not have a return type or save the list somewhere... what you currently have is so far from working that I'd suggest you start from scratch on this topic and read a good book or tutorial and follow it.

Comment: @nvoigt, it is in the question, I am trying to follow what is in the book Pro C# 5.0 and the .NET 4.5 Framework (Expert's Voice in .NET). I have started from scratch so many times. Obviously a beginner, but I need a point in the right direction as I am on my own here.

Comment: I'm no specialist of XAML but you probably should somehow expose Stuff to the world ;). Now it's exists only inside ListOfStuff function.

Comment: Then you may need a better book. You are not even close to a working solution.

Comment: @nvoigt, I don't think the book is the problem, me on the other hand....

Comment: Then get a book that is better suited for *you*. It's perfectly fine, not everyone can work with every book or tutorial. All I'm saying is that you don't have a small "change this one piece" coding problem. You need to follow a good book or tutorial, this is nothing we can solve here on the fly.

Comment: @AbinMathew, that is one BIG problem I am facing. I don't know how to go about making `public properties` with a collection.

Comment: @KyloRen try this way to create a property for your `stuff`
 public List<string> Stuff
        {
            get { return _Stuff; }
            set 
            { 
                    _Stuff = value;
            }
        }

Comment: @AbinMathew, logman's answer was the key for me, I just could not wrap my head around how to `get` and `set` the `list collection` . Thanks so much for all the help, as I have been struggling with this for a long time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [data binding combobox in wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37754973/data-binding-combobox-in-wpf)

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:CollectionClass x:Key="StuffColl"/>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="164,137,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" ItemsSource="{Binding Stuff, Source={StaticResource StuffColl}}" SelectedIndex="0"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And class

```
public class CollectionClass
{
    public List<string> Stuff { get; set; }

    public CollectionClass()
    {
        Stuff = new List<string>();
        Stuff.Add("A");
        Stuff.Add("B");
        Stuff.Add("C");
        Stuff.Add("D");
    }

}
```

Comment: Awesome, that answered all my questions. I just could not get around how to `get` and `set` the `collection`. Your example is working in my application.

Comment: Absolute brilliant, I am now able to bind this data with other controls such as tree view etc. Thanks again , this helps enormously!!!

Answer (score 1):

The most simple way to fix your example is:

Create edit your xaml grid like this:

```
<Grid>
<ComboBox Name="NamesComboBox" Background="Yellow" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5" ItemsSource="{Binding UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Path=Value}">
</ComboBox>
</Grid>
```

Then edit the file xaml.cs like this

```
        public MainWindow()
    {
        ObservableCollection<string> Stuff = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        Stuff.Add("Stuff1");
        Stuff.Add("Stuff2");
        Stuff.Add("Stuff3");
        Stuff.Add("Stuff4");
        InitializeComponent();
        NamesComboBox.ItemsSource = Stuff;//here you set the itemsSource
        NamesComboBox.SelectionChanged += NamesComboBoxOnSelectionChanged;// or you can create this on xaml like SelectionChanged="NamesComboBoxOnSelectionChanged"
    }
```

Finally create the method

```
  private void NamesComboBoxOnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs selectionChangedEventArgs)
    {
        var selectedString = selectionChangedEventArgs.AddedItems;
    }
```

this variable contains the string you select on combo box.

There are many ways to fix your example but this seems to me the fastest

Comment: How would you put that collection into a separate class to be called on? That is what I am really having difficulty getting right.

Comment: Create a separate class then create an instance in xaml.cs and then populate that instance

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a go.